# the subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, subquery

I'm trying to make a 'sales performance' table in html.
 Here's the query:

```
select DR.ACCNO, DR.NAME, DR.X_MONTHLYTARGET, DR.AGEDBAL0, DR.LASTMONTH, DR.MONTHVAL,
    (select SUM(ASI.SalesValueTaxExclusive) 
from dbo.DR_ACCS DR     
        inner join dbo.Analytics_SaleInvoice ASI on DR.ACCNO = ASI.AccountNumberAnalysis
     where ASI.PeriodID = 229      and DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y' 
    group by DR.ACCNO) as nov    

from dbo.DR_ACCS DR    
where X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y'   
group by DR.ACCNO, DR.NAME, DR.X_MONTHLYTARGET, DR.AGEDBAL0, DR.LASTMONTH, DR.MONTHVAL
```

Which just falls over saying more than 1 result.
I've tried to make head/tail of other posts but I'm lost.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove `group by DR.ACCNO` and check

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this subquery:

```
(select SUM(ASI.SalesValueTaxExclusive) 
 from dbo.DR_ACCS DR inner join
      dbo.Analytics_SaleInvoice ASI
      on DR.ACCNO = ASI.AccountNumberAnalysis
 where ASI.PeriodID = 229  and DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y' 
 group by DR.ACCNO
-^
) as nov
```

As highlighted, the problem is the `group by`.  Instead, you want a correlated subquery:

```
(select SUM(ASI.SalesValueTaxExclusive) 
 from dbo.Analytics_SaleInvoice ASI
 where DR.ACCNO = ASI.AccountNumberAnalysis and
       ASI.PeriodID = 229  and DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y' 
) as nov
```

This removes the unnecessary table reference to `DR_ACCS` in the subquery.  So, now the condition refers to the table in the *outer* query.  With this condition, you don't need a `group by` clause.  The subquery only aggregates one account at a time.

EDIT:

This full query should work:

```
select DR.ACCNO, DR.NAME, DR.X_MONTHLYTARGET, DR.AGEDBAL0, DR.LASTMONTH, DR.MONTHVAL,
       (select SUM(ASI.SalesValueTaxExclusive) 
        from dbo.Analytics_SaleInvoice ASI
        where DR.ACCNO = ASI.AccountNumberAnalysis and
              ASI.PeriodID = 229 and
       ) as nov 
from dbo.DR_ACCS DR    
where X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y'   
group by DR.ACCNO, DR.NAME, DR.X_MONTHLYTARGET, DR.AGEDBAL0, DR.LASTMONTH, DR.MONTHVAL;
```

The condition `DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y'` is redundant in the subquery, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code, but it now says DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER is invalid reference.

Comment: @Bevan . . . The outer query defines `DR`.  I didn't include it in the answer because I was focusing on the subquery.

Comment: Yes, but I even tried using the full name instead of shortening it, still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are using group by in subquery. Subquery should not return more than one row. If you remove group by clause from subquery it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It _works_ as such, but it returns the same figure for all accounts, not the correctly summed figure for each account.

Answer (score 0):

Which clearly says that multiple rows are returned from this query because of

```
    (select SUM(ASI.SalesValueTaxExclusive) 
     from dbo.DR_ACCS DR     
     inner join dbo.Analytics_SaleInvoice ASI on DR.ACCNO = ASI.AccountNumberAnalysis
     where ASI.PeriodID = 229      and DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y' 
     group by DR.ACCNO) as nov
```

Comment: Yes, but how to get thos multiple rows summed?